What exactly does the clutch do?
So I am learning how to drive and from a few videos on youtube, I know that pressing the clutch disconnects the engine and gears from the wheels.
Now the question is:
I had pressed the clutch and the car was still as it should be. I put the 1st gear and the car starts rolling back as I release the brakes. But I release the clutch and it starts to roll forward??
Since there was no acceleration given, the only force should have been gravity and surely the clutch can't change slope of the road so without the accelerator how does pressing or releasing the clutch determine direction of motion?
Even when the car stops for some reason, instructor asks me to again press and release the clutch slowly and says that I need not worry about accelerator(as the car can move for eternity without it?).

the clutch does not disconnect the gearbox from the wheels


how does pressing or releasing the clutch determine direction of motion?

A car propels itself by applying torque to the wheels that are in contact with the ground. That results in a forward force.
(disregarding stop-and-go) An internal combustion engine that is on will always be running and rotating the flywheel even when you don't press the accelerator.
When you want to start a manual car from a standstill you will want to get the clutch to the "bite point" where the clutch just engages the flywheel and starts applying torque to the transmission. At the bite point the clutch will slip and allow the output of the engine and the input of the transmission to be at different RPMs and transmit torque. The actual mechanism there is he exact same as applying the brakes without locking the wheels.
Once you are actually moving you can fully release the clutchpedal (or gear up to second gear and then release the clutch).
When coming to a stop you will want to disconnect the engine from the wheels to prevent the engine from stalling. You will know that you are going too slow when the car starts jerking violently.
Some cars can start from the idle RMP without using the accelerator. This depends on the car and the torque curve of the engine. In general diesels will have an easier time doing that compared to gasoline engines.

There is an addition thing the clutch assembly does which is be a damper between the engine and the transmission which smooths out the ride. If you look at a clutch plate you will see a set of springs. As torque is transmitted through the clutch it will allow those springs to compress


Since there was no acceleration given, the only force should have been gravity ...

No, the engine is running - typically at about 1000 RPM. If you let the clutch out gently enough this will accelerate the car slowly to a constant (but slow) speed.

... and surely the clutch can't change slope of the road so without the accelerator how does pressing or releasing the clutch determine direction of motion?

Pressing the clutch disengages the connection between the engine and gearbox and (if the brakes are released) the car will roll as determined by gravity. (Of course, if very close to level the rolling friction of the tyres, etc., will hold the car in position.) When the clutch is engaged the direction of motion is determined not by gravity but by whether a forward or reverse gear has been selected.

As others have stated in either answers or comments, the clutch does not connect directly with the wheels. It connects the engine with the gear box, which then activate the rest of the transmission system of the motor vehicle.
In answer to your question,

how does pressing or releasing the clutch determine direction of motion?

It doesn't determine direction of motion. Direction of motion is determined by the gear that has been selected. The numbered gears are for forward motion and R (reverse) is for backwards motion. Neutral is selected by placing the gear stick into the neutral position between the gear positions. If you engage the clutch (releasing, or taking your foot off, the clutch pedal) when the gear stick is in neutral the vehicle won't move, if the vehicle is on flat ground. If the car is on a slope and no brakes have been activated and the car is in neutral, it will roll down hill.
In relation to this statement,

I had pressed the clutch and the car was still as it should be. I put the 1st gear and the car starts rolling back as I release the brakes. But I release the clutch and it starts to roll forward??

You should not be rolling backwards. This is how you can potentially crash into a vehicle, or anything else, behind you. If the vehicle is facing uphill you need to do a handbrake start as you engage the clutch, so you don't roll backwards. This involves having the handbrake (parking brake) engaged and first gear selected and in a coordination between both feet you slowly push on the accelerator and at the same time you gently raise your foot off the clutch until you sense the clutch is starting to grip and you then release the handbrake and the vehicle moves in a forward direction, uphill, without rolling backwards (downhill).
A reverse handbrake start is done to prevent uncontrolled forward motion of the vehicle when the vehicle is facing downhill. In this situation, reverse gear is selected and the same handbrake, gear and accelerator actions as mentioned above apply and the vehicle will move in reverse uphill, without rolling forwards (downhill).
The statement bemuses me,

Even when the car stops for some reason, instructor asks me to again press and release the clutch slowly and says that I need not worry about accelerator(as the car can move for eternity without it?).

From a standing start, a car can move forwards or backwards without use of the accelerator if the gear selected is first or reverse. If absentmindedly, the gear selected was second or higher (not a good practice) use of the accelerator will be required.
Another bad practice is to start the engine without having pushed in the clutch pedal. By pushing in the clutch before starting the engine. The engine is decoupled from the gearbox and the rest of the transmission system and the car won't move unexpectedly if the gear stick is in a gear position & the engine starts.
During my college years a friend told me how his sister was being given driving lessons by their father and no-one had checked to see if the car was in neutral before doing anything. The sister wasn't told about putting her foot on the clutch before starting the engine and when she started the engine the car jerked forwards unexpectedly and crashed into a large water tank - not a good thing.
From a standing start on flat ground you should:

Make sure the handbrake is on
Ensure the gear stick is in the neutral position
Check your surrounding for people, other vehicles or hazards
Push in the clutch pedal
Start the engine
Select first or reverse gear, depending on which way you intend to
travel (you might be reversing out of a parking bay)
Use your indicators if needed, such as moving out of parallel
parking bay
Check your surroundings again
Take you foot of the clutch and if needed apply the accelerator
slowly and gently and move


As per our mechanics education as apprentices:
The clutch provides a temporary neutral

This allows for changing between gears or selecting neutral. It should not be used for long periods - when pulling away the clutch "slip" should not exceed 3 seconds. Even in reverse the clutch should not be slipped but engaged and the throttle used to control speed.
As for "I had pressed the clutch and the car was still as it should be. I put the 1st gear and the car starts rolling back as I release the brakes. But I release the clutch and it starts to roll forward" you need to match releasing the brakes with engaging the clutch so there is no "roll back" (that gets a fail during the driving test in some places). The car moves forward as the engine starts turning the gears providing forward (or reverse depending which gear is selected) motion.
One exercise I did with my kids was to get them to engage the clutch without using the throttle on a flat surface - this is clutch control.
Your other misconception "I know that pressing the clutch disconnects the engine and gears from the wheels." is that the clutch disconnects the engine from the gearbox.
The clutch is used to disconnect the power flow from the engine flywheel to the geardtrain. When the gearbox is in neutral, only the input shaft and layshaft will be turned at engine speed when the clutch is engaged, when disengaged they will slow down to a stop. The gearbox output shaft is in direct connection with the differential which is directly connected to the driven wheels - be they front or rear so the output shaft always rotates at a speed in ratio to the ground speed of the car.

@jsotola what do you think is wrong?

@jsotola then what is wrong with what I have stated? Unless you want me to talk about input shaft, layshaft and output shaft?

@jsotola did you read that correctly? I quoted what the OP wrote where it was stated that the "disconnects the engine and gears from the wheels" AND I put that in italic to make it obvious what I was quoting from the original post. I then followed with "the clutch disconnects the engine from the gearbox" as a better explanation.

@jsotola it does not disconnect the gears from the wheels...

@jsotola what is confusing is the missing comments...
